# Can Dart Streams emit a value if the stream is not done within a duration?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, rxdart

I am working on a Flutter app using blocs to control the state of the view. I want to call and external API and if it responds quickly, show the results right away by `yield`ing the result state. However, if the call takes more than, say, 5 seconds, I would like to yield a state indicating that the response is taking a while while still waiting for the API to return. How can I do this with Dart Streams, either natively or with RxDart?

Comment: check `Stream.timeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using `Stream.timeout`. Thanks @pskink!

```dart
Stream<String> delayedCall() async* {
  yield 'Waiting';
  final apiCall =  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((_) => 'Complete');
  yield* Stream.fromFuture(apiCall).timeout(
    Duration(seconds: 3), 
    onTimeout: (eventSink) => eventSink.add('Still waiting'),
  );
}


void main() {
  final stream = delayedCall();
  stream.listen(print);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the Futureshave a delayed timeout that you can use for example

```
try{
  var timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
    yield SlowAPI();
  });
  YourFeature.whenComplete((){
    timer.cancel();
  });

  yield Success();
}catch(e){
   yield Error();
}
```

Comment: But I still want to keep trying for the success after the timeout. And because it's taking a long time, I don't want to start it over. I've edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: ok im going to edit the answer as well but is a odd case

Comment: so you can create a timer when the timer is completed will yield the slow api state, but if the future arrive first will cancel the timer

Comment: But the third line will yield to the callback function, not the outer function.

Comment: So the question is: does the `yield SlowAPI()` - which is within an anonymous callback function of the Timer actually percolates up to the "main" level of the `async*` call?

Comment: So this yield doesn't even compile for me: `Undefined class 'yield'.`